# Kaizala to SharePoint Attachment

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, kaizala

1. Kaizala to SharePoint with MS Flow
   When Kaizala Custom Action to SharePoint Attachment Upload then get this Error.
   *The file id 'IMG_21-06-09_000051942_1.jpg' is not valid*.**
2. Kaizala to Team with MS Flow

Also Kaizala Check-in Action to Date get in Binary Values "1623298559000"it will not convert in Standard Indian Date/Time.**

3. Team Flow Card

How to add Multiple Email ID in Team Flow Card?

Anybody Can help me of this above mention topic?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check this [article](https://kaizala007.wordpress.com/2020/02/27/handling-images-in-kaizala-part-ii/) to capture the image and upload it in a SharePoint document library.
2. Explain your query clearly with more details.
3. Which teams connector are you using for this scenario?